# VBA very easy program and struggle

Tags: vba

so I am getting errors for some reason "next without for"
here is the code:

```
Sub test()
Dim y As Integer
y = 0

For i = 1 To 7
    For j = 1 To 7
        If Cells(i, 1) = Cells(j, 1) Then
            y = y + 1

    Next j

        Cells(i, 2).Value = y
        y = 0
Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Your if needs an `End If`

Comment: http://www.databison.com/vba-if-function-using-if-else-elseif-if-then-in-vba-code/

Comment: where exactly? I tried all variations

Comment: Before `Next j`

Comment: its working! thx :)

Comment: @Tsin Accept the answer so it will be helpful to people with the same problem :)

Comment: @Teasel Sadly, folks with 1 reputation don't seem to come back and accept answers very frequently.

Comment: @KacireeSoftware Sadly you're right ...

Answer (score 1):

The problem doesn't come from your `For ... To ... Next` but from your `If` condition that you forgot to close with the `End If` instruction.

```
Sub test()
    Dim y As Integer
    y = 0

    For i = 1 To 7
        For j = 1 To 7
            If Cells(i, 1) = Cells(j, 1) Then
                y = y + 1
            End If 'You forgot to end the condition
        Next j

        Cells(i, 2).Value = y
        y = 0
    Next i
End Sub
```